# Cannot get inner HTML when trying to show div element

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am supporting a really old legacy application that is about to be taken down which is written in aspx. I have a `<div>` element inside a page (Example.aspx) that I am trying to make visible in the code behind (Example.aspx.cs) based on a checkbox checked value. However I keep getting this `Cannot get inner content of '' because the contents are not literal` error and thus my div is not being rendered. I referred to this SO post: [Cannot get inner content of '' because the contents are not literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610249/cannot-get-inner-content-of-because-the-contents-are-not-literal/16368857) which mentions that this will not work on controls that are run on the server i.e `runat="server"`. I cannot access the Wordpress url referenced in the one answer from this SO post that was suggested: [Cannot get inner HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20954946/cannot-get-inner-html) - and this one ([Cannot manage to change the inner html of a div element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37881010/cannot-manage-to-change-the-inner-html-of-a-div-element)) is not applicable to my question.

Example.aspx:

`<div id="testID" runat="server">  <!--some content ---></div>`

Example.aspx.cs:

```
 protected void checkBoxName_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      if(!checkBoxName.Checked)
           testID.Visible = true; //The exception is thrown here
 }
```

Comment: Please add the code where you get `Cannot get inner content of '' because the contents are not literal` error.

Comment: @SelimYildiz The exception is thrown this line `testID.Visible = true;`. I edited the question with a comment

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown the code for the `CheckBox`, but considering that you have an event handler for it, I assume you have something like the following:

```
<asp:CheckBox id="checkBoxName" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="checkBoxName_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" Checked="true" /> This is my CheckBox
<div class='myClass1' id="testID" runat="server">This is my DIV</div>
```

in which case, the following should work:

```
protected void checkBoxName_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox cBox = (CheckBox)sender;
    Control divCtrl = cBox.Parent.FindControl("testID");

    if (divCtrl != null)
    {
        //set value
        divCtrl.Visible = cBox.Checked;
    }
}
```

---

This has been tested using the following:

**Create a new project** - `ASP .NET Web Application (.NET Framework)`

- For **Project Name**: CheckBoxTest
- Click **Create**
- Click **Empty**
- Uncheck **Configure for HTTPS** (optional)
- Click **Create**

**Open Solution Explorer**

- In VS menu, click **View**
- Select **Solution Explorer**

**Add Web form**

- In Solution Explorer, right click <project name>
- Click **Add**
- Select **New Item**
- Click **Web Form** (name: default.aspx)
- Click **Add**

**default.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="CheckBoxTest._default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:CheckBox id="checkBoxName" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="checkBoxName_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" Checked="true" /> This is my CheckBox
        <p />
        <div class='myClass1' id="testID" runat="server">This is my DIV</div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**default.aspx.cs**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace CheckBoxTest
{
    public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void checkBoxName_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBox cBox = (CheckBox)sender;

            //find desired control
            Control divCtrl = cBox.Parent.FindControl("testID");

            if (divCtrl != null)
            {
                //set value
                divCtrl.Visible = cBox.Checked;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Resources**:

- [Call OnCheckedChanged event from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21905663/call-oncheckedchanged-event-from-javascript)
- [Make checkbox of detailsview to be checked by default for insert new record?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13112551/make-checkbox-of-detailsview-to-be-checked-by-default-for-insert-new-record)
- [How to select a div element in the code-behind page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19265103/how-to-select-a-div-element-in-the-code-behind-page)

**Additional Resources**:

- [Call JavaScript function when CheckBox is checked or unchecked](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Call-JavaScript-function-when-CheckBox-is-checked-or-unchecked.aspx)

Comment: Pity I can't attach screenshots but I have your code exactly like that and I still get the same error...

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955769/better-way-to-find-control-in-asp-net

Comment: The page has update panels. It might explain why the thing doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this looks to be as simple as possible.

However, DO keep in mind that HTML rendering does NOT occur when you set a control visible = false.

In other words, you set visible = false, then other code (in most cases client side) will not then see this "div" or whatever - since it not at all rendered.

I don't know what other code is involved here, but I would test/try/consider using style to hide, and thus the HTML is still there - but does not show.

so, try this:

```
 testID.Style["display"] = "none";
```

and to display, then

```
 testID.Style["display"] = "normal";
```

However, perhaps some udpate panel is involved here - and that will change how this works. If the button/checkbox is say inside of a update panel, and the div is not? Then this will not work.

However, if the button/checkbox is outside of the update panel, then it should work ok. So, if update panels are being used, this could effect behavours.

Comment: There are some update panels on the page but the actual div itself is not nested inside an update panel

Comment: Well, the checkbox being inside of a update panel would cause this. So while the div could be in a update panel, and the checkbox outside? That will work The reverse is not going to work!. So if checkbox is inside a update panel, and div inside - no problem. Checkbox inside panel and div outside - no go.

Comment: Also, even if you using a master + child page, we again assume the code and markup is in the child page - and we don't care + worry about the master page.